# why my php curl doesn't work when CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST = 0?

Tags: php, curl

*environment：*

> OS：macOS
>
> PHP：7.1.30
>
> curl：7.65.0
>
> openssl：1.0.2r

I've been trying to call https api with php curl library，it return 403 http code on my machine but 200 on my workmate's Mac.

[this is the output html image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTnVT.jpg)

**my curl configure code：**

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

the configure code above works on my workmate's Mac.

But if I set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST = 1 or 2, it works too.

Has anyone been in this situation？

Comment: Is the target website a self-signed certificate? If so, modifying `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` or adding certificate to the trust list will work.

Comment: @CalosKao Unfortunately not a self-signed certificate.